# Why am I unable to generate code using Randoop where classes of other Jars are involved?

Tags: testing, automation, code-generation, randoop

I'm trying to generate Java unit test cases using Randoop. Suppose I've a class named ABC. Inside class ABC, I've instantiated the `Logger` class of `log4j` as a field and this field is being accessed by a method. I've listed class ABC in `myClasses.txt`. Now while running the `gentests` command, I'm getting `noClassDefFound error` for the Logger instance. Please help if we're missing on something?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you give show (essential parts of) the code that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put Logger class also in myClasses.txt. Also provide log4j properties file in java 
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:...

Answer (score 0):

The command line for running Randoop includes a classpath argument.  Is the log4j jar file included in the classpath provided to Randoop?  Your command line should look something like:

```
java -classpath %RANDOOP_JAR%;%ABC_HOME%;%LOG4J_JAR% randoop.main.Main gentests --testclass=ABC
```

where `%ABC_HOME%` is an environment variable indicating where your `ABC` class resides, and `%LOG4J_JAR%` refers to the location of your log4j jar file.  (This is in Windows notation.  Linux paths use ":" separators rather than ";" separators.)  And of course you don't need to use environment variables.  You can just plug in the appropriate paths.